# CATIA V5 VBA: get CATPart linked documents

Tags: vba, hyperlink, catia

Is there a way for a catscript/catvbs/catvba to access all the Pointed Documents of a CATPart?

I need to retrieve a list of all the Pointed Documents filepaths (similarly to what an interactive user gets with the menu View-->Edit Links-->Pointed Documents tab)

CATIA V5 Automation seems to expose such APIs only for CATDrawings. For each **DrawingView** object you can get the Pointed Document with:

```
PointedDocFullPath = MyDrawingView.GenerativeBehavior.Document.Parent.FullName
```

**But**, how can I get **CATPart** links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CAIEngine and stiDbItems:

```
stiEngine = catia.GetItem("CAIEngine")    
# The GetStiDBItemFromAnyObject() needs a document object as parameter.
stiDbItem = stiEngine.GetStiDBItemFromAnyObject(product.ReferenceProduct.Parent)
stiChildren = stiDbItem.GetChildren()
for i in xrange(1, stiChildren.Count + 1):
  fullPath = stiChildren.Item(i).GetDocumentFullPath()
```

Good luck