# CATIA VBA, get CATPart and CATProduct linked documents

Tags: vba, catia

I need to have access to the list of all the Pointed Documents. (Similar to View-->Edit Links-->Pointed Documents tab)

There exists a solution for CATDrawing but, seems there is no way for parts and products.

Here is similar question:
[CATIA V5 VBA: get CATPart linked documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823475/catia-v5-vba-get-catpart-linked-documents)
but the answer is for "CATIA SMARTEAM Integration", but I need it for CATIA V5R20 standalone.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823475/catia-v5-vba-get-catpart-linked-documents): They suggest to use CAIEngine and stiDbItems

Personally, I am using MyProduct.GetMasterShapeRepresentationPathName and it works just fine to get CATPart linked documents.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was for stand alone CATIA as CAI is integrated in CATIA even without installed Smarteam. Therefore try CAIEngine and stiDbItems.